# How can i make rtl text to continue the left part below

Tags: html, css, arabic, right-to-left

I have this really long Right-to-left arabic paragraph:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/09b6xoaa/4/

But i would expect that when the line is too long it would continue the left part below ("end of the line this should be on the second line"), and not to break line at the right end of the line("start of the rtl line") which is supposed to be the start of the line.

I can't seem to find anywhere the answer to this behaviour which seems to me that is a very basic behaviour to expect.
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you!

**17-01-28 12:16 Updated description and fiddle link**

**Update: seems like my problem was lying within a python library(weasyprint) for rendering html into pdf which does not have support for RTL

Thanks everyone!**

Comment: do you know arabic? it is not required to break the manner you think

Comment: I don't. But let's say i want to. Does it make sense to break it like this? Is it possible?

Comment: see updated answer, it might help you understand the way words flow from right to left.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like i have a problem with how django templates render the variables in a rtl div. But now at least i know how it should normally work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For right-to-left scripts like as arabic, the long texts will break at correct position by default (as for left-to-right).

Please see the following Persian (like as Arabic) text which i embed equivalent engligh words beside each number such that you can follow the words as they are written in html code and presented in output web page:

```html
<p dir="rtl" >
کلمه اول - کلمه دوم - کلمه سوم - کلمه چهارم - کلمه پنج - کلمه شش - کلمه هفت - کلمه هشت - کلمه نه - و انتهای جمله.
</p>

<p dir="rtl" >
کلمه اول first- کلمه دوم second - کلمه سوم third - کلمه چهارم fourth - کلمه پنج five - کلمه شش six - کلمه هفت seven - کلمه هشت eight - کلمه نه nine  - و انتهای end جمله.
</p>

<p dir="rtl" >
  کلمه اول firstWord-
  کلمه دوم secondW -
  کلمه سوم thirdW -
  کلمه چهارم fourthW -
  کلمه پنج fiveW -
  کلمه شش sixW -
  کلمه هفت sevenW -
  کلمه هشت eightW -
  کلمه نه nineW -
  و انتهای end جمله.
</p>
```

Please note that the right-to-left texts must be aligned right by default.

Comment: But my question is... how do i make the line break at the left side? Because if the direction is right to left it doesn't make sense to break at right. It's like having a sentence like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/09b6xoaa/3/ I'm i missing something?

Comment: do you have a very special case which want to reverse line break at special position or you just want an RTL lang like as arabic to be braked at its correct position? if it is the second (and i think so as you say its a basic case) then you don't worry about it, its ok by default. you have to set only text-align. and its good for you to know that text-align:left will treat as right for rtl languages! (trust me, i know arabic)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you r looking for

```css
#rtl{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p id="rtl" >arabic valuearabic valuearabic valuearabic valuearabic valuearabic valuearabic valuearabic value2<b> arabic label2 </b> ar value1 <b>ar_label1</b></p>
```

Comment: not really. Take a look at: https://fiddle.jshell.net/09b6xoaa/2/ The end of the line which in RTL direction would be the most left part of the line. I expect that part to go on the next line (below).